# when creating menu in wordpress it shows database can not be inserted

Tags: wp-admin

0

i am facing the same problem if anyone has any solution then please reply i am facing with long time and not able to crack this solution please help someone... i will be eagerly waiting for reply...

whenever i go and try to create menu after entering name it shows database can not be inserted... and nowadays this is becoming a huge problem please someone reply and give solution

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/424393/edit) to provide more information. What is the *exact* text of the error message? Does the error occur if you turn off all your plugins and switch to a default theme like 2024? Is your version of WordPress up to date? Have you contacted your hosting provider about this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can you add screenshots or copy paste the errors you are seeing instead of describing them with words? Which page/user interface are you using to create menus? ( there are multiple places to do this and it might matter )